# Why can't I store associative arrays in MongoDB document?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I would like to store a date in the format JJ/MM/YYYY into an associative array like this:

```
'day' => $day,
'month' => $month,
'year' => $year
```

I've done this quite easily but once I try to store the document in the collection, the date is stored in the document like this:

```
0 => $day
1 => $month
2 => $year
```

I've done a PHP debug of the object just before "flushing" and it showed the keys associated with the values but once in the collection, it has been reset with numeric keys.

My entity look like this:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="collection")
 */
private $date;

public function getDate()
{
    return $this->date;
}

public function setDate($date)
{
    $this->date = $date;

    return $this;
}
```

And the controller part:

```
$date = $movie->getDate();
$keys = array('day', 'month', 'year');
$values = explode('/', $date);
$dateArray = array_combine($keys, $values);
$movie->setDate($dateArray);
```

I would like to precise that I'm using the Doctrine ODM for MongoDB on Symfony 4.

So here are my questions:

**1)** How to store the array with the associated keys?

**2)** Are the keys in MongoDB document are "fixed"? I mean, am I sure that the key 0 will always be associated with $day and key 1 with $month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `hash` [type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types):

> `hash`: associative array to MongoDB object
>
> `collection`: numerically indexed array to MongoDB array

```php
/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="hash")
 */
private $date;
```

Comment: Thank you. This indeed resolve the issue. Just a question: in the doc, it says `If you are using the hash type, values within the associative array are passed to MongoDB directly, without being prepared. Only formats suitable for the Mongo driver should be used.`, what does it mean when it says "formats suitable for the Mongo driver"?

Comment: As I understand this means only scalar values and arrays or values accepted by mongo (e.g. \MongoDate instead of \DateTime)

Answer (score 1):

You can use EmbeddedDocument feature provided by Doctrine ODM.

First, you need to create EmbeddedDocument DateExample in AppBundle\Document\DateExample.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument()
 */
class DateExample
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="int")
     */
    protected $day;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="int")
     */
    protected $month;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="int")
     */
    protected $year;

    // getter and setter
}
```

Then, you can use DateExample in your Example document. So the Example.php file will be similar to this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
* @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ExampleRepository")
*/
class Example
{

    /** @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="DateExample") */
    private $date;

    // ...
}
```

And the controller part:

```
$date_example = new DateExample();
$date_example->setDay(21);
$date_example->setMonth(05);
$date_example->setYear(2019);

$example = new Example();
$example->setDate($date_example);

// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it looks like a little "too much", is this the only solution for preserving array keys in a MongoDB Document Doctrine?